# Не получается подключиться к mongo в docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mongo

Пытаюсь подключиться к контейнеру mongo через еще один контейнер тем самым заставив код ждать пока запустится, но этого не происходит (сам код отдельно работает, т.е. запустить mongosettings после того как главный контейнер запустится)

Фото docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongo:
    image : mongo:latest
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
    # volumes:
    #   - ./mongo_db_data_container:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: adminimda

  mongosettings:
    image : mongo:latest
    container_name: mongoClientTemp
    links:
      - "mongo:mongo"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    command: sh -c 'mongo --host mongo -u admin -p adminimda --authenticationDatabase admin --eval  "db.getSiblingDB('ShareLinker').createUser({user:'Sr233', pwd:'greatPassword_QWErty', roles:[{role:'readWrite',db:'ShareLinker'}]});"'
```

Сам DockerFile

```
FROM mongo:latest

VOLUME [ "/data/db" ]

ENTRYPOINT "init.sh"

EXPOSE 27017
```

Лог сервиса mongosettings:

```
MongoDB shell version v5.0.4
connecting to: mongodb://mongo:27017/?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server mongo:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to mongo:27017 (172.21.0.2:27017) :: caused 
by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Пытался использовать дополнительно команду bash sleep 'sometime' но выкидывает ошибку

```
usr/bin/sleep: /usr/bin/sleep: cannot execute binary file
```

Как мне решить данную проблему если команда не ожидает полного запуска монго?

Comment: потому что монго еще не успела стартануть, а другой контейнер пытается подключиться, добавьте слип перед подключением `command: sh -c 'sleep 15 && mongo --host mongo `

Comment: Спасибо, это сработало!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

потому что монго еще не успела стартануть, а другой контейнер пытается подключиться. можно добавить ожидание перед подключением `command: sh -c 'sleep 15 && mongo --host mongo  – ...`, либо сделать грамотно и ожидать когда конкретно можно будет подключиться

Comment: Как можно сделать так, чтобы код ждал запуска монги?

Comment: я бы добавил вместо слипа ожидалочку `while ! mongo <connection> --eval "db.version()" > /dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 0.1; done` будет каждые 100мс проверять доступность

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подсказать где вы раздобыли эту информацию про то, как настраивать? Очень хочу разбираться в этом. Направьте пожалуйста меня.

Comment: я запустил ваш композ и увидел в логах, что коннект идет до того, как монго скажет, что готов принимать коннекты. тогда я добавил слип и все заработало. 
про команду while выше. я просто умею писать while, добавил команду и > /dev/null.  но я думаю можно еще много примеров в интернете найти, если погуглить

Comment: Хорошо. Что заничит ">", "/dev/null", "2>&1" ?

Comment: весь вывод указанной команды спихнуть в черную дыру! 
это один из способов сделать программу по-настоящему безмолвной

Comment: Вы очень интересно пишете. Я вас не понимаю, извините :(

Comment: вы пробовали гуглить, что это такое? https://habr.com/ru/post/138591/